# Can I reuse an alginate bath for reverse spherification?

Tags: molecular-gastronomy, spherification

Can I REUSE an alginate bath for reverse spherification? If I use a solution of alginate today, can I use the same solution next week? How should it be optimally stored? How long will it keep. How many "spheres" can be produced by a batch of alginate?

Comment: I voted up your question solely based on the fact that you said, "reverse spherification". Kudos.

Comment: I have no hard data to back this up, so I'm making it a comment not an answer. My sense is that it should be good for at least 3-4 days in the refrigerator, like most perishable foods.

Comment: Oh, and another note - you might like the ideasinfood gellan method better than alginate. http://blog.ideasinfood.com/ideas_in_food/2012/03/encapsulated-balsamic-vinegar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site say you can use it again, just make sure you strain it before you store it
http://www.molecularmixology.co.uk/index.php?act=viewRecipe&recipeId=34

This site says you can store it for a couple of days in the fridge
http://www.molecularrecipes.com/spherification/7-tips-making-spherification-caviar/

As for how many spheres can be produced - I'm afraid that would be completely dependent on how large you make your spheres.